# How do we know how long speciation occured?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution, molecular-evolution

Just as we use radiometric dating to age rocks, what is the method used to age how long ago speciation occurred in genetics?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_clock

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phylogenetics and the Tree of Life](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26255/phylogenetics-and-the-tree-of-life)